# unhandled exception access violation C++ Visual Studio before main is called

Tags: c++, access-violation, unhandled-exception

I'm getting the following error as soon as I click run to debug in Visual Studio 2013 . . .

[image]

I'm not sure how to proceed as I put a breakpoint on the first step in main and it does not hit this breakpoint.

History: I was handed a working program and was asked to integrate an updated dll.  The dll had a couple I/O changes which I updated in the wrapper to enable the program to build. Now when I run I get the mentioned error.

Any next step advice as to what to check from here?

Comment: You may want to look at any static objects, which are constructed before `main()` is called.  Such objects are constructed in no particular defined order, so if there are logical dependencies between the objects, you can run into problems.  This is a recurring problem that even has its own name:  the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: Where do you end up if you press Break in this window? What is in the Call Stack?

Comment: Opens a tab called "Source Not Available" There is a title in this tab "Frame not in module".  Then "The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location."

Comment: It looks like at some point before main (either in DllMain on during initialization of some global object, either it the program itslef or in the DLL) a function pointer (or a virtual table entry) containing an invalid address is called. That's why Call Stack could be interesting, if it contains decipherable information.

Comment: Call stack has an address on first line.  On second line it has "[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]", then next line "[External Code]"

Comment: Can you right-click in the Call Stack window ans select "Show External Code"? Does it then show anything of value?

Comment: > UAS.exe!_except_handler4(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord, _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD * EstablisherFrame, _CONTEXT * ContextRecord, void * DispatcherContext) Line 91 C